# Adobe AE with Element3D to work with Intel Graphics

Tags: after-effects, video-editor

I use Element3D most of the time when I edit videos, however, there's a problem.
This Adobe After Effects Plugin works with NVIDIA GeForce Palit 210 1GB but I didn't use the graphics card because it performs too slow / let's say not capable for 1920×1080 resolution but for 1280×720 only.

At the moment, I'm using my motherboard's/processor's built-in graphics card/display/driver, but it happens that I can't use the Element3D because it says that it can't initialize the OpenGL. I'd check my processor graphic specs and I find it capable though of OpenGL 4.4. **My question is, How am I able to make Element3D run with my graphic preference/spec/settings.** (See Specs and Error Messages below)

**My PC Specs:**

- Main Storage: 256GB Crucial SSD
- Secondary Storage: 500GB Hitachi HDD
- Processor: Intel Core-i3-6100 @ 3.70Ghz (6th Gen)
- Memory: 8GB (7.44 Usable)
- OS: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit
- Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 530, 2GB (Excellent in games and video editing, even at 1080p, it's just that Element3D Don't Work)

**Error Messages:**
First, when dragging the effect to the timeline:

[image: First Attempt]

Doing it again, and opening its dialog box / control panel or whatever you call it (after clicking ok on this picture, it makes my Adobe AE Not responsive and I'll just close it)

[image: Second Attempt]

Answer (score 0):

You should check VideoCoPilot's website in regards to system requirements.

Based off first glance; your system is not cut out for working with Element3D in AE.

AE alone is going to strain your system. At the very least you're going to want to run E3D in AE on a i7 processor setup (preferably XEON); as many cores as possible, as AE can multi-thread; and not rely on an onboard graphics card.

I run E3D on a dual E5-2697 v2 (48 Cores HT), with 128 GB Ram; and a Titan Black GPU and I still wish it could be more responsive and faster.

At the VERY least; you're going to need to bump up to 32 GB ram; recommend 64; and a much better processor.

Your OS and system services are going to tie up 1.5 GB of your 8 GB ram; and AE alone will hog another 3-4 GB with no plugins running. It's my opinion you simply don't have the power to run this config on your system.

Comment: All works fine even it's just that. It is just that the E3D dont work with Intel HD Graphics. I just wish there's a workaround for it. I even use it with Twitch, Optical Flares and whole set of Red Giant plugins.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't!**

See supported GPU list here on Videocopilot website:

http://www.videocopilot.net/docs/element/installation_and_compatibility/specifications/